# ffmpeg is not recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg

The following code gives me an error in the CMD window (Visual studio 2013 - c# project):
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command

```
Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.mp3");
                //    sw.WriteLine("mypassword");
                //    sw.WriteLine("use mydb;");
            }
        }
```

This error happens only when i run the command "ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.mp3" from the code. the other way works - running the command straight from CMD.. any suggestions to make it work from the code?

Comment: why do you try to start `ffmpeg` inside a `cmd`? you should be able to run it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set where the `ffmpeg` executable file is.

```
info.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\myFFMPEGDir";
```

At the moment, it's trying to look into the same directory as your process for `ffmpeg`. It sounds like ffmpeg is not there so you need to set the path.

Alternatively, you can write the entire path in the command.

```
sw.WriteLine("C:\\myFFMPEGDir\\ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 test.mp3");
```